# What does "また朝までコース" mean?

Tags: translation

It's a small hashtag on twitter.
[https://twitter.com/hashtag/また朝までコース](https://twitter.com/hashtag/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E6%9C%9D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9)

Does the コース here always refer to a meal? A plan of action?
Are they saying they're gonna party till morning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. They are saying they're gonna party till morning.

We might say

> 終電{しゅうでん}逃{のが}したから、朝{あさ}までコース。(カラオケ？)
>
> So, we missed the last train home. Let's party till morning(Karaoke?).

I do not think it always relates to a meal, say drinking beer at Izakaya, but it could be. I might be wrong tough, I think it is a set phrase with the party. I do not say "昼{ひる}までコース。" or something.